# OWASP ESAPI filters SafeRequest() vs SecurityWrapperRequest() filters

Tags: java, owasp, java-security, esapi

I am using esapi-2.1.0.1v and trying to include **OWASP-ESAPI filter utility**.
which one is the difference between SafeRequest and SecurityWrapperRequest and best practice to add for case below:

request.getParameterMap();

**return new SecurityWrapperRequest(request).getParameterMap();** //org.owasp.esapi.filters.SecurityWrapperRequest()

or

**return return new SafeRequest(request).getParameterMap();** //org.owasp.esapi.filters.SafeRequest()

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** `org.owasp.esapi.filters.SafeRequest` class. (The closet to that would be a `org.owasp.esapi.filters.SafeRequestTest` class under **src/main/test** that is a JUnit test, so you definitely don't want *that* one.)

The only classes in the `org.owasp.esapi.filters` package that are actually JavaEE servlet *filters* are: `ClickjackFilter`, `ESAPIFilter`, `RequestRateThrottleFilter` and (despite its name), `SecurityWrapper` (which in hindsight, should have been called `SecurityWrapperFilter`). That `SecurityWrapper` filter uses the 2 classes, `SecurityWapperRequest` and `SecurityWrapperResponse`, which can also be used as classes that assist you in constructing your own JavaEe servlet filters.

All but `ESAPIFilter` are adequately described in the package Javadoc at https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.2.3.1/org/owasp/esapi/filters/package-summary.html. `ESAPIFilter` is probably not useful to you unless you are using the ESAPI `Authenticator` interface.

Hope that helps a bit.